# How to call Model's function followed by eloquent function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

//controller.php

```
public function close(int $boxId): bool
{
    $box = Box::find($boxId)->close();
}
```

//model.php

```
public static function close()
{
    //need to update the is_open field to 0 for found Box
}
```

I am new to laravel, and I am not sure the above code is possible.
It would appreciate if you help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to actually explain what you want. We don't know what box or is_open is, or what it should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need it to be static. The following should make it work:

```
public function close()
{ 
    return $this->update([
        'is_open' => 0
    ]);
}
```

**or** you could just do this in your Controller:

```
public function close(int $boxId): bool
{
    $box = Box::findOrFail($boxId);

    return $box->update([
        'is_open' => 0
    ]);
}
```

`findOrFail()` will throw a `ModelNotFoundException` if the box is not found.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider upvoting/marking this answer if it helped you. See [when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

you can do by laravel eloquent [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes)

> local scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you
>   may easily re-use throughout your application. For example, you may
>   need to frequently retrieve all users that are considered "popular".
>   To define a scope, prefix an Eloquent model method with scope

in **model.php**

```
public  function scopeClose($query,$flag)
{
    $query->where('is_open',$flag ?? 0);
    //need to update the is_open field to 0 for found Box
}
```

Comment: It works, But I don't want to use scope function. Thanks for your answer.